# How can I remove mold stains from a pan?

Tags: cleaning, mold, stoneware

A few weeks ago I made some homemade bread pudding. We had a few servings of it, the weather got hot and humid, and I soon learned that mold really likes bread pudding too. The pan is a stoneware pan.

I rolled up my sleeves, got some really hot water, and scoured it as best as I could but it still has dark spots and a moldy "funk" to it. I don't really want to use it like this. Is there a way that I can clean this pan or is it a lost cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use bleach to remove mold and mildew stains from my bathroom and while the process would be gross, I would think that once thoroughly washed the bleach wouldn't cause any harmful effects to the pan or to future snacking humans.

Comment: No more harmful than the chlorine in your pool, or your municipal water.

Comment: This is exactly what I would do.  First I'd try bleach mixed with water in the ratio suggested by the bottle.  If that was not successful, I'd step up to using small amounts of pure bleach and allow it to sit for a 5-10 minute period before rinsing/scrubbing.  Pure bleach will do amazing things to mold/mildew.  I've seen grout between tiles start out black with mold and look brand new after being treated with pure bleach.

Comment: If for some reason you're uncomfortable with bleach, you could also try white vinegar. (Vinegar can be used anyway to remove any bleachy smell -- more of an issue if you're using bleach to clean plastic containers.)

Answer (score 2):

I've used Milton sterilizing fluid for jobs like this - especially tea stains in mugs and even turmeric.

Answer (score 1):

I've had that happen a couple of times. I read that you can boil water and vinegar in a pot to get some of those dark spots loose and easier to clean. Stoneware gets seasoned with use so if you use too harsh of cleaning chemicals food for the next few meals may stick more than usual. If your pan/pot is not something you can put over a direct flame then I would fill it with water & white vinegar and put it in the oven at 200+ for a while. Just keep an eye on it so that the water doesn't evaporate below the stain. 
Edit: On my non-porous cookware I use bar keepers friend and it does great. It's mildly acidic.

Answer (score 0):

Bleach does not kill mold. It just bleaches it white and eventually comes back. Borax kills mold and it never comes back!

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Please be aware that you are answering a question that is over 10 years old, and as such the asker is unlikely to see your answer.  Also, this answer could be improved by citations for its factual claims.